# Can i end While loop with function?

Tags: php, function, while-loop

I tried to google this and i think it can't be done but i have to ask anyway.
If i have while loop?

```
while ($smth > 1)
{
  func();
}
```

Is there a way i could exit the while loop immediately with that function inside it?
Maybe that function returns something that stop loop?
I tried

```
func(){ 
return break;}
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: You could return a value (perhaps Boolean) from the function and check the return.  Ie ‘if ( func() ) { break; }

Comment: you need to return something. Side note: You don't need the "break" with a "return"; the latter stops the execution of a script to run any further. You say it doesn't work though; is that your actual code or there's something else that we need to know/see?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner The function is called from within the `while` loop, so `return` will stop the function, not the loop.

Comment: @Max Right, so maybe a `while true{...} ....`? *> edit* or `do while` *< edit.*

Comment: @Max Strike that ^ I misunderstood the question. Not the beginning of it though, heh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible the way you've done it -- you can't return a break. But you can return a value that could signal to exit the loop.

```
function func() {
  return true
}
```

And then

```
while($smth > 1) {
  if(func()) break;
}
```

This will run the function, but it will also check it's return value to verify it does not need to exit the loop. If the function returned true, the `if` statement is satisfied and so a `break` will occur. If the function doesn't return explicitly, the `if` will not be satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

You sort of can get out of that while loop from inside that function by throwing an exception. Your teammates will not like you anymore, however.